# mouseWheel stops scrolling until I move mouse elsewhere Chrome - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scroll, mousewheel

I have a section based on scrolling. The idea is that you scroll you travel from 1 to 2 to 3 then you progress to the next section.

All works fine except 1 glitch - if mouse does not move and only the wheel is used, after the 1,2,3 is over, the scrolling stops working and does not allow to scroll further downwards and same happens for the upwards.

I've checked and found some articles explaining that it can be a Chrome issue because it works fine for me on Edge, Safari. I see this issue only in Chrome.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

[Here is my fiddle where you can see it in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/aidadev/pzetd06m/24/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var $container = $('#scrolling-container'),
    top = 0,
    lastScrollTop = 0,
    proceedFlag = true;

var scroller = function(event) {
    top += $container.height() * (($(this).scrollTop() > top) ? 1 : -1);

    var firstBarItem = jQuery(".bf-content:first-child"); 
    if (top == 0 || top <= lastScrollTop){
        // upscroll code
        var previousBarItem = jQuery(".bf-content.active").prev();

        if(previousBarItem.length && previousBarItem.hasClass('bf-content')){
            jQuery(".bf-content.active").removeClass('active');
            previousBarItem.addClass('active');
        }else{
            jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop': jQuery(".top-section").offset().top}, 300, 'swing', function(){
                var $target = jQuery(".top-section");
                $target.focus();
            });

        }
    } else {
        // downscroll code
        var nextBarItem = jQuery(".bf-content.active").next();

        if(nextBarItem.length && nextBarItem.hasClass('bf-content')){
            jQuery(".bf-content.active").removeClass('active');
            nextBarItem.addClass('active');
        }else{
            jQuery('html, body').animate({'scrollTop': jQuery(".bottom-section").offset().top}, 150, 'swing', function(){
                var $target = jQuery(".bottom-section");
                $target.focus();
            });
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = top;
    if(proceedFlag){
        $container.stop().animate({scrollTop: top}, 300, 'swing', function() {
            $(this).clearQueue().one("scroll", function() {
                $(this).one("scroll", scroller);
                jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({'scrollTop': jQuery("#scrolling-container").offset().top}, 300, 'swing');
                jQuery("#scrolling-container").focus();
            });
        });

        return;
    }
}

$container.one("scroll", scroller);

});
```

Comment: im having same problem, did you solve it somehow?

Comment: @DimaMalko hey, not yet, but it is working quite differently now which doesn't seem to be a bug atm. If I have more info on it, ofc will share it here.